# Do I need to create an abstract method for toString and equals?

Tags: methods, equals, abstract, tostring

so my program is creating Quadrilaterals, and I was told to make abstract methods for findArea() and findPerimeter(), but do I need them for toString() and boolean equals method?

```
abstract public class Quad {
private int s; //Base top
public Quad(){
    s = 1;
}
Quad(int s){
    this.s = s;
}
abstract public int findPerimeter();
abstract public int findArea();
abstract public String toString();
abstract public boolean equals(Object o);
public int getS() {
    return s;
}
public void setS(int s){
    this.s = s;
}
```

}

```
class Square extends Quad{
private static int numSquares = 0;
private int s, iD;
public Square(){
    super();
    s = super.getS();
    numSquares ++;
    iD = numSquares;
}
public Square(int s){
    super(s);
    s = super.getS();
    numSquares ++;
    iD = numSquares;
}
public int getNumSquares(){
    return numSquares;
}
public int getID(){
    return iD;
}
public void setID(int iD){
    this.iD = iD;
}
@Override
public int findArea(){
    return (getS()*getS());
}
@Override
public int findPerimeter() {
    return (getS())*4; 
}
public String toString(){
    return "Side length is "+getS()+", Area is "+findArea()+" and Perimeter is "+findPerimeter();
}
public void decreaseNum(){
    numSquares --;
}
public boolean equals(Object s){
    if (s instanceof Square){
        Square temp = (Square)s;
        if(getID() == (temp.getID())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

So here's the code, thank you for reading and helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that in Java all class inherits from Object and the latter at the same time implements the toString and equals methods, so in any of your classes can redefine the behavior of these methods without having to declare as abstract in the parent class (Quad).

You can get this book for learn more about the good principles of object-oriented programming with java [Principles of Object-Oriented Programming with Java](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=548612)